# Remote deployment with Dropkick

Tags: c#, .net, continuous-deployment

I do lots of deployments in my everyday work. And it really hurts. Recently I came  across the [dropkick](https://github.com/chucknorris/dropkick) and it seems brilliant for me.
But the most valuable feature I need - [remote execution](https://github.com/chucknorris/dropkick/wiki/Run-Remote-Processes) - is not documented enough.
If someone had experienced such an issue, could you point me out some basic steps to do? How to configure local and remote PC?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Did you look at the Dropkick Wiki? It lists remote execution under Features.

https://github.com/chucknorris/dropkick/wiki/Run-Remote-Processes

Comment: Yes. I've put the link in my original post. It is still overwhelming to understand.